# How to clip a raster with polygon with no "NoData" pixel outside of polygon

Tags: raster, gdal, clip, nodata

I have a polygon with this shape:

[image]

The polygon is diagonal.

And I have a raster that covers all of pixels in the minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) of the polygon.

I used QGIS tool "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" to clip the raster by the polygon shape.

The resulting raster is again a rectangle that has "NoData" value for any pixel outside of polygon.

[image]

For the reason of disk space, I want to really clip the raster by polygon and have no pixel at all outside of polygon.

Is it possible? or rasters should always be rectangles?

if possible, how can I do it with QGIS or GDAL?

Comment: Rasters are rectangles and filled with pixels. You can save a lot of disk space by compressing your image because continuous nodata area can be compressed effectively even with lossless method like LZW or DEFLATE. Your data looks like "trajectory" and there are special file formats for that purpose but they require special software.

Comment: In fact, my data is a survey of the bottom of river for a length of river. So I guess there is no way to avoid having too many "NoData" values outside of the polygon (river).

Comment: Not really with traditional raster approach. But you can cover the length of river with smaller slightly overlapping rectangular rasters and view them together as a virtual raster. That is possible to do with GDAL and QGIS. If you are interested I may write how to do that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, please, I would like to know it.